# How can I implement an early stopping criteria - Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, object-detection-api, early-stopping

Fairly new to the [Object Detection API here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models), using tf-gpu==1.15 for training and 2.2.0 for evaluation as well as python 3.7.

I am able to utilize data augmentation as well as adjust the decay of the learning rate in the ssd_mobilenet_v1.config file, but I am not sure how to go about implementing a way for the model to stop training if I am confident the loss will not get below a certain value no matter how many more steps it trains.

How or where do I configure / implement early stopping criteria?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `EarlyStopping` callback from tensorflow. Refer tensorflow documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/EarlyStopping).

Create a callback using -

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

es = EarlyStopping(
    monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=3, verbose=0, mode='auto',
    baseline=None, restore_best_weights=False
)
```

- `monitor` - Change the `monitor` param to `loss` if u don't have validation data & want to stop training if training loss stops decreasing for 3 consecutive epochs. Also, u can change it to `accuracy` if u wish to stop training based on accuracy instead of `loss`.
- `patience` - Number of epochs to wait before stopping the training if loss doesn't decrease or accuracy doesn't improve

Then pass it to `fit` function while training -

```
history = model.fit(X, y, epochs=10, callbacks=[es])
```

There are many examples online, u can check them!

Comment: Ok thank you, but where in the object detection API would it make sense for me to implement this? Not too familiar with tf callbacks.

Comment: You can define callbacks anywhere in the script but before calling `fit` method. Usually people define the model, compile it, create callbacks if required & then call the fit method on it.

Comment: The script used to train, like a train.py?

Comment: Yeah, like train.py

Comment: but there is no model.fit() method in tensorflow object detection. Any suggestion where to call the callback in train.py of tensorflow object detection ?